# Reveal image from right to left with width?

Tags: css, image, height, width, clip-path

I have tried looking at answers of similar questions here but nothing solves my problem.
[Quarter of a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1J6K.png)
I want to increase the width of my image from right to left. I have tried `position absolute:0` and `right:0` as suggested around here but to no avail. The width seemingly increases from right to left but the left side of the image is revealed first.

What I want to do is increase either the width from right or the height from the bottom of the image, so it should appear that the line goes up.

I have managed to get the animation I want using clip-path like this:

```
@keyframes circleanim3 {
0%{
    clip-path: inset(100% 0% 0% 0%);
 
}
100%{
     clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0%);    
}
```

Unfortunately, clip-path doesn't seem to be supported in edge or safari. Is there any other simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ratio of your image or it's `height` and `width`, you can use the [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and the [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) css property:

```css
:root {
  --img-width: 600px;
  --img-height: 337px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% 0;
  width: 0;
  height: var(--img-height);
  animation: rightToLeft 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes rightToLeft {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: var(--img-width);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src='https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/a9c7e461090fc25097e6391a5bb823b0f28ba008/1672b/images/css/object-fit/example-object-fit.jpg' class='alligator-turtle' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the problem is object-position is not supported in safari.

Comment: @septick Yes it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position/#Browser_compatibility